# Will 700x35c fit my Giant Cadex 980c frame or are they too big in any way?

Tags: road, giant

My Giant Cadex 980c has 700x28c tires. Will 700x35c tires fit the frame? Make clear if you want to know anything else.

Comment: Have you tried measuring the clearance of the current tires?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what model year you have, but based on the 1989-1991 models, no.  [This spec page](https://geometrygeeks.bike/bike/giant-cadex-980c-1989/) gives 28mm as the max tyre width for the 1989 version, and  various pictures I've found of 1989 and later versions show there isn't space for wider tyres.

For example, this picture of the front forks, note this is only a 25mm tyre: [image: Head-on view of cadex] ([image source](https://retrobikerotterdam.com/products/giant-cadex-980c-52cm-shimano-105))

Or this picture showing the space between the chainstays:
[image: cadex bare frame]
([image source](https://villaveloframes.wordpress.com/2017/06/14/quangs-giant-cadex-980c/))